# Hacking attempt, process running under 'apache' user

Tags: centos, security, apache-httpd, curl, selinux

Our system blocked an hacking attempt coming from a local process running under the **apache** system user.

```
Process not allowed.

{
"USER": "apache 16",
"PID": "617",
"%CPU": "0.0",
"%MEM": "0.0 80",
"VSZ": "556 3",
"RSS": "904",
"TTY": "?",
"STAT": "S",
"TIME": "0:00",
"COMMAND": "curl -v -u -d yyyy http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/"
}
```

How could the apache user run curl?

From the /etc/passwd file:

```
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
```

Shouldn't this block **apache** from running any command?

We are running CentOS release 6.7 (Final) with SELinux enforced.

Comment: I think a buggy php site was hacked and php running as apache user. This is so common in webhosting business.

Comment: We are running on a dedicated server. The Apache access log don't show anything weird around the hacking time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

No, it just means that the user cannot log in and run a shell, he can execute commands though.

Just try the following, as root:

```
mkdir test
chown apache:apache test
sudo -u apache touch test/file
```

And now the user `apache` has used the command `touch`.

It is the very idea of a system user to execute commands/run progams/deamons etc. with their specific ID and the permissions following thereof.